# Must I remove the @Override annotation?

Tags: java, annotations

Following code giving an error near the  `public void control() {`.

EClipse giives a tip to remove the @Override annotation also. I went throudh the [docs.oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html) and found that *If a method marked with @Override **fails to correctly override** a method in one of its superclasses, the compiler generates an error.*

I don't understand what is meaning of "fails to correctly override"?

```
public class PersistenceFlowController implements controllers.FlowController {
   @Override
   public void control() {
      // Do some works here
   }
}


package controllers;
public interface FlowController {   
   void control();  
}
```

Comment: Specify the exact error message, in a shortened form, in the title, and the long form in the post. Also search for such error message.

Comment: Ah!. I just put it as previous to check for the matching quesions. and forgot to edit before posting it. My Bad pst! Thanx for mentioning

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In JDK 1.5, `@Override` could be applied only to methods from a parent class. In JDK 1.6 and up, it can be used for interface methods, too. My guess is that you have Eclipse set for JDK 1.5 compiler compliance. You can check or change this in the "Java Compiler" tab of the project properties dialog.